# Is "taken" a keyword in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda, named-scope

Straight to the question.
I have a query like this:

```
@issue_books = current_user.issue_books
@already_issues =  @issue_books.taken(params[:id])
```

where `taken` is a named_scope defined as below:

```
scope :taken, lambda { |book_id| where(returned: false).where(book_id: book_id)  }
```

Now everytime I run this query:

```
@issue_books.taken(params[:id])
```

I get an `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` error.

If I rename `taken` to something else like `taken_books`, all seems to work fine.

So my question is: is `taken` a keyword in ruby? If not can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Have defined any function named `taken` in your model, esp issue_book.rb?

Comment: @AnandVeeramani no man I aware of this thing I havent defined anything in `issue_books`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a ruby keyword, but it appears to be a method defined on scopes.

Try this:

```
@issue_books.method(:taken).owner
#=> ActiveRecord::Delegation
@issue_books.method(:taken).source_location
#=> (...)/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb
```

So the scope `taken` you have defined is probably overshadowed by a definition in `ActiveRecord::Delegate`.

**Update**:
I did some digging, and `taken` seems to be defined as an alias for `limit` in `Arel::SelectorManager`, a dependency of `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: I remember now yes it alias for `taken` thanks man for reminding me that